# manyToOne is creating new products

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I am trying to implement Sylius Cart Bundle, but every time I add a product to the cart, a new product is created.

This is probably link to my line:

```
cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

In my YAML File:

```
Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\CartItem:
type: entity
table: app_cart_item    
manyToOne:
    produit:
        targetEntity: Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\Product  
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]                       
        joinColumn:
            name: product_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

But if take it off, I get an error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\CartItem#produit' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 3test2. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})

According to the doctrine doc, this error occurs when you set a new object.
But I am only getting an existing object By ID:

```
$product = $this->getProductRepository()->find($productId);
$item->setProduit($product); //this generates the error
$item->setUnitPrice(5); //this works fine
```

I don't understand why it's save as a new object.

If I use `merge` instead of `persist`, I get the same error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship...

Comment: Could you show the form?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I'm not sure wich form you want to see. If it's to add the product I am just calling "/cart/add?productId=3" wich is the 3 lines of code in my question. If i comment the "setProduit" line it works but the product_id is set to null

Answer (score 1):

Found it (finally...) !

I had 2 entity manager mixed up. This iw why the doctrine wanted to store it as a new object all the time.

The mistake was in the services.yml file, on a listener.

Maybe it can help someone to look in the good direction.